# consulta de mySQL, obtener el minimo de cada categoria

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy muy trabada con una query.
Para el ejemplo que les comparto, requiero obtener el registro completo para cada columna -categoria, valor, survey_date- correspondiente al de la fecha del survey_date mas antigua para cada "categoria".
Es decir, por cada "categoria", necesito recibir la fecha mas antigua y su valor asociado.

Desde ya muchas gracias, les comparto ejemplo:

| survey_date | categoria | valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | cat1 | 100 |
| 2022-08-29 | cat1 | 300 |
| 2022-08-15 | cat2 | 200 |
| 2022-07-18 | cat1 | 400 |
| 2022-06-27 | cat3 | 200 |
| 2022-06-06 | cat3 | 500 |

Por ejemplo, para cat1, quiero que la query me devuelva unicamente

| survey_date | categoria | valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | cat1 | 100 |

para cat3:

| survey_date | categoria | valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-06 | cat3 | 500 |

ya que para cada categoria, el valor asociado a la fecha minima es ese

Comment: prueba algo así: select titulo, valor, min(survey_date) from mitabla group by titulo, valor

Comment: Empecé haciendo eso, me encontre con problemas ya que me trae como referencia la menor fecha de toda la tabla, no por titulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rocío, te había dado la respuesta a tu pregunta, pero la he actualizado específicamente con el ejemplo que enviaste (incluyo código para que pruebes directamente con los datos de tu ejemplo):

```
CREATE TABLE tutabla
(
    survey_date DATE NULL,
    categoria varchar(10) NULL,
    valor INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO tutabla (survey_date, categoria, valor) VALUES ('20180101','cat1',100)
INSERT INTO tutabla (survey_date, categoria, valor) VALUES ('20220829','cat1',300)
INSERT INTO tutabla (survey_date, categoria, valor) VALUES ('20220815','cat2',200)
INSERT INTO tutabla (survey_date, categoria, valor) VALUES ('20220718','cat1',400)
INSERT INTO tutabla (survey_date, categoria, valor) VALUES ('20220627','cat3',200)
INSERT INTO tutabla (survey_date, categoria, valor) VALUES ('20220606','cat3',500)

SELECT T1.survey_date, T1.categoria, T1.valor
FROM tutabla T1
WHERE T1.survey_date=(SELECT MIN(T2.survey_date)
    FROM tutabla T2 WHERE T1.categoria=T2.categoria)
```

Resultado:

| survey_date | categoria | valor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-01-01 | cat1 | 100 |
| 2022-08-15 | cat2 | 200 |
| 2022-06-06 | cat3 | 500 |

Comment: Hola! ahi agregué un ejemplo. Lo que estoy querendo encontrar son de cada categoria el valor que tenga la fecha mas vieja. y no tener que recurrir al WHERE, ya que es un dataset muy extenso

Comment: @RocioRamos creo que no te estas explicando muy bien, yo entiendo que la fecha minima y la fecha mas vieja son lo mismo, mejor comparte todo el esquema de la tabla y si tienes el enunciado del problema pues tambien compartelo para ayudarte mas facil

Comment: Agregué un nuevo ejemplo, por si te ayuda a entender

Comment: @RocioRamos, he actualizado la respuesta que te había dado anteriormente, incluyendo script para creación de la tabla y llenado de registros con los que enviaste de ejemplo, el query que obtiene lo que necesitas y una tabla de Resultado para que compares si el resultado es el que esperas. Saludes, y confirmas si esto te resuelve o sigues requiriendo ayuda. No olvides calificar la respuesta si es satisfactoria ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias @AugustoAltamirano!!!

Comment: Me alegra que te haya sido de ayuda, @RocioRamos. No olvides calificar la respuesta, saludes.